# Is it possible to automatically show apps which are installed to "~/Applications" in the system's "Applications" folder?

Tags: finder, applications, install, dock, launchpad

Some applications are not installed to the usual root "Applications" folder, but to the one inside the user's home directory. They then don't show up when I click on the Applications folder icon in the dock. 
While they sure can be started using Launchpad, I'm more used to start applications via the application folder link in the dock.
Is there a way to keep my habit but also see the user's applications?

Comment: Pro Tip...Use Spotlight instead.  Press `Cmd-Space` and start typing the app name - its much, much faster than looking in a window for apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is what I would do:**

1. Create *aliases* for the apps already in: **~/Applications**

   - Select the apps in **~/Applications** and drag an drop into **/Applications** while holding down: <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd>
2. Create an **Automator** Folder *action* that will create an *alias* for any new app placed in **~/Applications** into: **/Applications**

   - In **Automator**, **File** > **New**, then select: **Folder Action**
   - Set **Folder Action receives files and folders added to ~/Applications**
   - Add a **New Aliases** *action* setting **In:** to: **/Applications**
   - Save as, e.g.,: **Alias My Apps to Apps**

[image: Automator Folder Action workflow]

---

To work with **Folder Actions** afterwards, you can bring up **Folder Actions Setup** using **Spotlight** by typing in e.g. **Folder Actions Setup** until it shows, and then press: **Enter** Or, *right-click* on any folder in **Finder** and select **Folder Actions Setup…** from the **Services** section of the pop-up menu.

[image: Folder Actions Setup]